# how to get group list from linkedin using linkedin api?

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

HI i wanted to get entire group list from linkedin using linkedin api,if not possible atleast get some groups from linkedin to process the data.can any one help how to get group list?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, then could you add the code you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for your qucik response,i have been using scribe 1.3.jar to get some of my basic operations done.i have hard coded the group value and then pass it to my method to get data of that particular group.now i have to get group list,get it iterated and pass each group number to my method and then get the data.

Comment: String resource1 = api.getResource(Urls.getGroupPostsUrl(groupId, 0));i would get the reponse as json string using the line which contains the group information

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901268/linkedin-groups-api-getting-group-logo-for-multiple-groups-in-a-single-api-req

Answer (score 0):

You can get groups using following code:

```
  final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory =  LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKey, consumerSecKey);
    final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(token, tokenSecret);

        GroupMemberships memberships = client.getGroupMemberships();
        for (GroupMembership membership : memberships.getGroupMembershipList()) {
            System.out.println(membership.getGroup().getName());
            System.out.println(membership.getGroup().getId());
            System.out.println(membership.getMembershipState().getCode());
        }
```