# LinkedIn Groups API - Getting group logo for multiple groups in a single API request

Tags: php, rest, linkedin-api

Using [LinkedIn Groups API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api), I am showing a list of groups the user is a member of on LinkedIn. Getting the list of groups in a single call is clear using

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name),membership-state)?count=50&start=0&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessKey;
```

**Task**

Now, I want to show the group logo image alongside the group name. However, this would mean for n groups, I have to do n more API calls, and this slows down the page load (e.g. for 50 groups).

The [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api) states,

> You can access details about one or more groups such as the ID, name, settings, and posts from any groups resource path.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{group-id}:(id,name,short-description,description,relation-to-viewer:(membership-state,available-actions),posts,counts-by-category,is-open-to-non-members,category,website-url,locale,location:(country,postal-code),allow-member-invites,site-group-url,small-logo-url,large-logo-url)
```

*I want to get the logo images of the mentioned group ids in a single API call.*

**What I have tried**

- A comma-separated-value for `{group-id}`, but it gives error

  Invalid value {xxx1,xxx2,xxx3} in key {id}
- A `/` separated value for `{group-id}` gives error

  Unknown field {xxx2} in resource {Group}

Kindly guide what I am missing here, as the documentation also suggests one or more groups and it is a genuine use-case.

Comment: What about `/groups::(1234,5678,9012):…`?

Comment: Getting error, 'Requesting multiple groups at the root level is not supported.'

Comment: And asking for the additional fields directly in the first API call you have shown in the first place doesn’t wok either?

Comment: The documentation example did not have it, but it could be possible. Let me try it.

Comment: It works! `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,small-logo-url,large-logo-url),membership-state)?count=5&start=0&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessKey;`

Comment: Kindly post it as an answer for future readers (and reputation love also) :)

Comment: Hi will you please post your code so i will use it in my site too

Comment: I would be unable to post the complete code, but this issue was resolved. Kindly see accepted answer below.

Comment: @GopalAggarwal, I used your code but failed (403 error). What's the `oauth2_access_token`, is it the `[access key](http://joxi.ru/V2VGo6BURE4eAv)`? If not, then how to get it?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin I suggest you try to get the basic examples working first (using the documentation), and then come to advanced uses. It's been long since I worked on this problem, and don't remember readily. Also, see if the answers below can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name),…`

You should be able to ask for all additional group fields you want directly in this call, by extending the field list after `group:(…` accordingly:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,
small-lo‌​go-url,large-logo-url),…
```